# Reorder keys after deleting from MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where the application has an ordered set of fields. Additionally there is the ability to delete one of the fields however, if you delete a row it doesn't reorder based on what was deleted, eg. `1, 2, 4, 5, 6`

Is there a way that I can reorder the list based on the above field to give me `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do this. The primary key is "just a value" it has no meaning and therefor the gaps or ordering does not matter. If it matters to you, that the column shouldn't be a PK

Comment: It's not a primary key or auto_incremented, its an ordered field, which I look up for a generated report. It exports the fields based on their order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know you deleted "3", then do:

```
update t
    set id = id - 1
    where id > 3
```

Comment: And btw, when he'll insert new rows in this table, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` won't consider it. In this case, the next new entry would have the id 7, not 6.

Comment: +1 @tsabz I am curious to know the same.. when we send a delete request to MYSQL (for bulk deletion), does it do a sequential or bulk simultaneous delete in the engine?

Comment: @tsabz . . . Unless I missed something, the question does not specify that this is an auto-increment column and only mentions deleting one row.  however, you make good points.  Although I think the bigger point is not to reassign auto-increment ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're right. It's kind of a habit to work with auto_increment for id columns :) Anyway, your answer will work without this. I made an answer too in case he needs the auto_increment handling.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wouldn't it be safer to add an order by clause?

Comment: Actually this will work thanks! It must be too early for me because I should have figured that out just by thinking on it!

Answer (score 0):

**This assumes the `id` column works with auto_increment**

I don't think there is a reliable "one-command-way" to do this. You could use Gordon's solution, but as I mentionned, it won't reorganize your ids properly.

Here would be my solution (assuming you can work with PHP or some other script language) :

1. Retreive all the table data.
2. Truncate your table.
3. Use `ALTER TABLE 'your_table' AUTO_INCREMENT=0` to reset the auto_increment.
4. Reinsert the data your retrieved before.

Here would be my way of doing this.

Comment: That would work if the ids were unique primary keys and auto increment, however several reports' fields are kept in same table.